# Use different file with functions in Webpack

Tags: npm, webpack, laravel-mix

I use Laravel Mix for compiling JS files. I want to move all my functions to another file named `functions.js.` In `app.js` I want to include this file.

**functions.js**

```
var functions = {
  test: function() {
    console.log('test');
  }
}
exports = functions;
```

**app.js**

```
import functions from './functions';
functions.test();
```

**Message From Console**

> Uncaught TypeError:
>   _functions__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default.a.test is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**functions.js**

```
    module.exports = {
        test: function () {
            console.log('test');
        }
    }
```

**app.js**

```
  import functions from './functions';

  functions.test();
```

OR:

**functions.js**

```
const test = () => console.log('test');
const test2 = () => console.log('test2');

module.exports = { test, test2 };
```

**app.js**

```
import functions from './functions';

functions.test();
functions.test2();
```